# Writing a Javascript regex that includes special reserved characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm writing a function that takes a prospective filename and validates it in order to ensure that no system disallowed characters are in the filename. These are the disallowed characters: / \ | * ? " < >

I could obviously just use string.indexOf() to search for each special char one by one, but that's a lot longer than it would be to just use string.search() using a regular expression to find any of those characters in the filename.

The problem is that most of these characters are considered to be part of describing a regular expression, so I'm unsure how to include those characters as actually being part of the regex itself. For example, the / character in a Javascript regex tells Javascript that it is the beginning or end of the regex. How would one write a JS regex that functionally behaves like so: filename.search(\ OR / OR | OR * OR ? OR " OR < OR >)

Comment: So, "how do I escape characters in a regex?" Any documentation should explain this on the first or second page.

Comment: I would not worry about what you don't want in the filename unless you will be mixing specifics and generalizations like `(.+)\.ext`. Its better to focus on what is allowed like `^\w+(?:\.\w+)*\.\w{2,4}$` The set that this `[^\/\\|*?"<>]` matches is imense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your stuff in a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) like so:

```
[/\\|*?"<>]
```

You're gonna have to escape the backslash, but the other characters lose their special meaning. Also, RegExp's `test()` method is more appropriate than `String.search` in this case.

```
filenameIsInvalid = /[/\\|*?"<>]/.test(filename);
```

Comment: `/[/\\|*?"<>]/` probably will generate error because the delimeter `/` is not escaped. Also, this is not a negative character class, won't filenameIsValid be TRUE if they exist?

Comment: As I said, the `/` character loses its special meaning inside the character class, so there's no error there. You misread the variable name: I called it `filenameIsInvalid`, so it will be `true` indeed :)

Comment: `/` has no *special* meaning in regular expressions no matter where it is. It must be an intelligent parser that already knows to include inner delimeters. All other parsers would generate a message like 'Unmatched [ in regex' as it tries to parse `/[/` -> `\\|*?"<>]/`.

Comment: Huh? There is no such thing as "intelligent parsers". A parser is either correct or erroneous. If you have an example of a parser that does not handle the above RE literal correctly, you should file a bug report.

Comment: Language parsers are not too intelligent. I was just trying to make a point. And, `filenameIsInvalid = /[/\\|*?"<>]/.test(filename);` failed in js, failed in other languages as well. Maybe you really did escape the delimeter and I don't see it. Js pass: http://www.ideone.com/3f2kx, Js fail: http://www.ideone.com/fwfAD, php pass/fail: http://www.ideone.com/cuzJI, Perl pass/fail: http://www.ideone.com/6rsse

Comment: Guess that's what happens when you use a 6 year old JS engine, adhering to a 12 year old standard. [That's a bug, fixed 3 and a half years ago](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=368019). Don't know about perl, but IMHO that's a bug in [PHP](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) too ("All non-alphanumeric characters other than `\ `, `-`, `^` (at the start) and the terminating `]` are non-special in character classes")

Comment: The sequence goes like this, 1 - Parse the container of the regular expression. 2 - Get the modifiers. 3 - Parse the regular expression. It is impossible to do it any other way. From http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html, "In JavaScript source code, a regular expression is written in the form of /pattern/modifiers .. forward slashes delimit the regular expression, any forward slashes that appear in the regex need to be escape". Character classes have nothing to do with the delimeter, it hasen't even been parsed yet.

Comment: Well `/[/\\|*?"<>]/` just tested this in a html page with local browser without errors, so you might be right about the character class. This would seem to be a bug in itself. Checking again it gives weird errors when delimeter moved around, so I'm chalking this up to browser bizarness.

Comment: Obviously you have no idea how parsers work. I highly recommend reading about tokenization, lexical analysis and finite state machines. Also you may want to [inform Jan Goyvaerts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/about.html) about the erroneous information on regular-expressions.info. I'm not gonna comment on this any further since it seems like a waste of time.

Answer (score 1):

Include a backslash before the special characters `[\^$.|?*+(){}`, for instance, like `\$`

You can also search for a character by specified ASCII/ANSI value. Use `\xFF` where FF are 2 hexadecimal digits. Here is a hex table reference. http://www.asciitable.com/ Here is a regex reference http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to escape the special characters. In javascript this is done by using the `\` (backslash) character.

I'd recommend however using something like [xregexp](http://xregexp.com/) which will handle the escaping for you if you wish to match a string literal (something that is lacking in javascript's native regex support).

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax of the regex is:

```
/^[^\/\\|\*\?"<>]+$/
```

The `[^` will match anything, but anything that is matched in the `[^]` group will return the match as `null`. So to check for validation is to match against `null`.

Demo: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RDg5H/).

Demo #2: [Comparing against null](http://jsfiddle.net/LJJT2/).

The first string is valid; the second is invalid, hence `null`.

But obviously, you need to escape regex characters that are used in the matching. To escape a character that is used for regex needs to have a backslash before the character, e.g. `\*`, `\/`, `\$`, `\?`.

Comment: "you need to escape regex characters". No, you don't.